# chrome - totally impossible to auto-open new TABS using scripts?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, popup

Is totally impossible to auto-open chrome tabs using scripts like:

http://jsfiddle.net/vyW3V/1/

or

```
window.open("http://www.google.com/", "_blank");
```

or similar??

Im trying using events like `click`, `trigger`, but:

- if browser's popup-block is enabled,  these pages can not be opened,
- when popup-block is disabled, the pages are opened as external window (like popup)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open a URL in a new tab using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript)

Comment: basically there's no standard for JavaScript to control browser behavior like this.

Comment: yes I have already look at this link, but seems not work now... maybe after some chrome's updates??

Comment: is there a way using jquery?

Comment: @miushock: read comments in your link.. no one working solution..